# Geometric solution of quintic equations

Tags: geometry, polynomials, roots

There are many method of geometric solution of quadratic equations (for example [Carlyle Circle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CarlyleCircle.html)).

Does there exist similar method  for the quintic equation?

Comment: Related: ["Geometric interpretation of a quintic's roots as a pentagon?"(http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1556406/409). In [my answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1559590/409), I show that, while the roots of a quintic aren't on *a* pentagon, they can be viewed as a combination of points on *two* pentagons (with a generalization to degree-$n$ polynomials.) In a [companion answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1560748/409), I walk through an example.

Answer (score 2):

None that I am aware of, but you might find references in [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/133211/can-the-unsolvability-of-quintics-be-seen-in-the-geometry-of-the-icosahedron) overflow answer helpful and interesting.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean geometric constructions with ruler and compass, then there can't be any such methods because $5$ is not a power of $2$. This is a weaker version of the fact that the general quintic is not solvable by radicals.

For other geometric methods, see the book [Geometry of the Quintic](http://people.reed.edu/~jerry/Quintic/quintic.html) by Shurman.