# Continous family of $n$-gons

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, plane-geometry

The statement of this problem asks to show that if $A$ and $B$ are two distinct convex $n$-gons there is a continous family of convex $n$-gons such that the first in that family is $A$ and the last is $B$. My first intuition is that convexity ought to be utilized at some point in this proof. Perhaps consider establishing a correspondence between the vertices and drawing the line segment in between. Then continuously translate the $n$-gon along the lines. Shape will clearly not be preserved but I think there is a way to do this preserving convexity. It is just not clear to me under which conditions this translation should be performed. Any thoughts?

Comment: Is a 5-gon formed by inserting a vertex at the midpoint of a side of a square considered a convex 5-gon?

Comment: @coffeemath's answer settles this quite elegantly. I'll mention that in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1559590/409), I describe how any $n$-gon decomposes into a "sum" of regular (convex, starry, & multiply-traced) $n$-gons. Any $n$-gon, then, can be continuously transformed into a regular convex $n$-gon by continuously reducing the contribution of the non-convex components. I've *wondered* ---but have never investigated--- how (or whether) one might maintain convexity throughout such a process if the initial polygon is convex. If do-able, we can transform $A$ to regular to $B$.

Comment: @Blue I toyed with that idea, making the furthest vertex from a proposed center move in a little, etc, winding up at an intermediate stage where all vertices on a circle, then moving things until n-gon is regular. But I thought the details would be involved. (Anyway that way one could avoid angles of 180 degrees during the deformation, if initially there were none.) [+1 on comment, I'll look at that answer soon.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 3-gons one can consider the circumcircle, and move points along the circle until it is equilateral, without going through nonconvex 3-gons (since there are none). Since both 3-gons can be thus made into equilaterals, a composition of the two deformations takes the first into the second.

Suppose true for $n$ gons, and consider two $n+1$ gons, and take three adjacent vertices $a,b,c$ from one of them and $a',b',c'$ from the other. For each of these, one can move $b$ (and $b'$) until it coincides with the midpoint of $ac$ or $a'c',$ without destroying convexity. (E.g. move it on the line connecting $b$ to the midpoint of $ac.$)

Now you have essentially two $n$ gons and can finish by the inductive hypothesis.